# GWT: Drawing ImageElement on context2D with rotation

Tags: html, gwt

I am looking for a way to draw an image on a context2D with rotation of the image.
I tried:

```
imageElement.getStyle().setProperty("transform", "rotate(-45deg)");
```

It did not work and the image was not rotated.
Any other ways to rotate the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`setTransform`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/canvas/dom/client/Context2d.html#setTransform%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29) method to apply the transformation on the `Context2D`, then `drawImage`.